# How to remove 0.0 from <apex:input type="number"> on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I created a Search `Visaulforce Page` which searches `Opportunity` records based on `Amount` and `Stage` values provided in the page.

If I don't enter any value in the `Amount` field, the value results in `0.0`. How can I make it `null` instead of `0.0`?

Here is the markup:

```
Amount : <apex:input type="number"  value="{!samount}"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in your controller simply by tweaking the getter:

```
public Decimal someAmount
{
    get { return (someAmount == 0) ? null : someAmount; }
    set;
}
```